# Can I know if the directory listing property is correctly set on an FTP server?

Tags: ftp, directory-listing

I have to create a specific directory structure on an anonymous FTP server. These directories will contain some metadata files that will be read from a bot of a specific service (...but this is not important now).

The important thing (these are basics requirements for the bot to be able to read the metadata files) are:

1) **Directory listings must be enabled, the so-called -Lrat switch**

2) **Also, they should be configured to generate Unix style directory listings**

I have no access to the FTP configuration and I have received the access from an IT but I am not sure that who gave me access has followed the previous configuration. Can I see it in some way? (looking at the server directory structure or in some other way)

Comment: This question needs to be addressed to the admin of the system concerned.

Answer (score 2):

You can verify these things very easily using a command line FTP client (or any ftp client for the first one). Under Linux you will have one built in, windows probably too but I'm not in a position to check right now.

Simply run `ftp user@server` and give your password when prompted. Once logged in give the `list` command and if you get something useful back directory listing is enabled. The format of that listing will answer the other question - just compare it to a Unix style listing as seen in the output from `ls -l` under Linux/osx/... (if you don't have access to a box running some Unix-a-like OS in order to check this, you'll fine many examples online)

In fact that switch looks like options for the `ls` command rather than for the ftp server to enable listing generally - many ftp severs running on Unix-like OSs will pass an `ls` command through to the underlying OS. I suspect that `l` should be lowercase in which case it turns on the long (detailed) listing format, the `a` tells it not to skip over "dot files" which it normally doesn't display, and the `t` and `r` options ask for sorting of the output in reverse order of the file last-modification timestamps (the default is to output in alphabetic order by name). If this is what is actually being required, login yachting the command line client and issue the command `ls -lrat` to see if you don't get an invalid command error and if the output is in the expected format.

Comment: Thank you but I am not sure to have well understand what are you saying to me. I have done the following step: 1) I entered into FTP account with my credential (using ftp command in my bash) 2) I entered in the directory that I have to check (using cd command) 3) now I tryed to execute the list command but I obtain this error message: ftp> list ?Invalid command What it mean?

Comment: And if I execute ls -lrat I obtain this:ftp> ls -lrat
200 PORT command successful.
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for /bin/ls.
09-21-13  07:50PM       <DIR>          RePEc
226 Transfer complete.

Comment: So what it mean? that this is not unix style?